# How to unitest with cython from .py file

Tags: python, unit-testing, cython, python-unittest

I tried to search for this problem on Google but fail.

I have a `.pyx` file constant a cython variable. Now I want to mock this variable for the test. What are the best ways to do that?

For example:

**.pyx**:

```
cdef dict example {
    A: B,
    C: D
}
```

I want to reference the `example` variable from the `.py` files.

I update my question as the request of Mr.David:

```
# Menu code
DEF CODE_TYPE_1ST    = 0
DEF CODE_TYPE_2ND    = 1

# Menu length
DEF CODE_LENGTH_1ST    = 4
DEF CODE_LENGTH_2ND    = 6

# Menu dictionary
cdef dict code_length_dict = {
    CODE_TYPE_1ST: CODE_LENGTH_1ST,
    CODE_TYPE_2ND: CODE_LENGTH_2ND,
}


class MenuCheck():
    def __init__():
        pass

    def process_menu(self, first, second):
        if first not in code_length_dict | second not in code_length_dict:
            raise CustomError(ErrorStatus.INVALID, 'Blad blad...')

        ...
```

Comment: Have you tried `cpdef`?  That's supposed to make a function available to the importing `py` module.  But even with that you might not be able to modify its value or use within the compiled code.

Comment: Oh! I have never heard it before. Let me try. Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: @hpaulj I tried `cpdef`. However I still raise `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'bladblad'`.
`def` → *OK*, `cdef` → *NG*, `cpdef` → *NG*

Comment: Your example pyx file won't compile. Could you show us what you've _actually_ done

Comment: I think you just need to define it as a normal Python variable (not `cdef`): `code_length_dict = { ... }`. There isn't much of a speed gain for making specifying the type to be `dict` so this doesn't lose you much.

Comment: You cannot, in general, do what you wish. You can do one of the following: test from within cython, expose your variables using getter routines or do as the others suggested: "def" instead of "cdef". Anyway, provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)